# iOS application is getting crashed if we continuously publish / unpublish the audio and video track, TwillioVideo SDK

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, twilio-video

#### Description

in my application I am publishing and unpublishing the audio and video tracks when user mute / unmute audio and enable / disable the camera. After 2 three continues tap the application is getting crashed.

I tried to disable the mic button interaction until the audio is not published, as we get callback in `localParticipantDidPublishAudioTrack` but for un-publish there is no callback. That logic is also crashing. How can I fix this crash

**Also please suggest what will be the side effect if I will enable/disable the audio track instead of publish / unpublish. Also what is the recommended  approach for both audio and video**

#### Steps to Reproduce

While on the call try monkey tap on mute button and from the code inside publish & unpublish the audio track on each respective tap

##### Code

```swift
@IBAction func micControlAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //Toggle mic
        guard let participant = callViewModel.getCallParticipant(type: .patient) else { return }
        if let audioTrack = participant.audioTrack as? LocalAudioTrack {
            if audioTrack.isEnabled {
                (participant.participant as? LocalParticipant)?.unpublishAudioTrack(audioTrack)
            }
            else {
                (participant.participant as? LocalParticipant)?.publishAudioTrack(audioTrack)
            }
            audioTrack.isEnabled = !audioTrack.isEnabled
            //This will call the observer and the UI will gets updated according to the need
            participant.micEnabled.property = audioTrack.isEnabled
      }
 }
```

Expected behavior: The user should be able to mute / unmute the mic without any delay.

Actual behavior: Application crashes 100% of time

Logs

```
libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called!
Pure virtual function called!
```

#### Versions

- Video iOS SDK 4.6.0 via CocoaPods
- Xcode 13.1
- iOS Version 13.6.1
- iOS Device iPad Air

Comment: Showing a stack trace of the crashed thread could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on suggestion on this [link](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-ios/issues/223), it seems that TwillioVideo 4.6.0 SDK is having issue and reverting to **TwillioVideo SDK to version 4.4.0** works fine.

The crash log when using version 4.6.0:

```
Thread 31 name:
Thread 31 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba0e39c4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3333434 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1609)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018e562f64 abort + 164 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019bd89bc4 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019bd89594 __cxa_pure_virtual + 24 (cxa_virtual.cpp:16)
5   TwilioVideo                     0x0000000105686668 0x104fe4000 + 6956648
6   TwilioVideo                     0x000000010568646c 0x104fe4000 + 6956140
7   TwilioVideo                     0x0000000105420e0c 0x104fe4000 + 4443660
8   TwilioVideo                     0x0000000105420db4 0x104fe4000 + 4443572
9   TwilioVideo                     0x0000000105499924 0x104fe4000 + 4938020
10  TwilioVideo                     0x0000000105499188 0x104fe4000 + 4936072
11  TwilioVideo                     0x0000000105498128 0x104fe4000 + 4931880
12  TwilioVideo                     0x0000000105499568 0x104fe4000 + 4937064
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f332da60 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:890)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f332cf5c thread_start + 8
```